# Where OpenERP (Odoo) finds the modules path?

Tags: odoo

I am using Odoo v.8. I want to find out where Odoo finds information where the modules are, to load them. I am aware there is a variable addons_path in the file openerp-server.conf. The only file I have found the variable in is opt/odoo/odoo/debian/openerp-server.conf. It has the following value:

```
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
```

However, the Odoo application is using modules from "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons" path. Where the Odoo retrieves this information from? If I have a new directory with new modules, where I can update the path? I have updated addons_path in opt/odoo/odoo/debian/openerp-server.conf with new modules path, but Odoo still cannot see the modules in Settings/Update Modules List. I have restarted the server.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add to the `addons_path` directive in openerp-server.conf, (separate paths with a comma) or you can use `--addons=` if starting your server from the command line.

Comment: I think you mean `--addons-path=`.

Comment: You're right: I checked and the command arguments parser accepts abbreviations for commands,a s long as they're not ambiguous. Nevertheless, the correct option name is `--addons-path` .

Comment: I have no idea why this answer was flagged as correct. Of course these statements are right, but they don't answer the question: why does Odoo use its installation path as addons path? And where to find that behaviour written in the odoo code?

Answer (score 2):

Odoo tries to initializes a set of paths to be loaded from the base addons directory. [Check the code for Odoo system path](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/modules/module.py#L83)

So, with the help of this method, it loads the basic addons directory and other directories that are added by **addons_path**.

Generally, we use addons_path at odoo-server.conf and save our addons directory path at it.

Note: the path must contain atleast one OpenERP/Odoo module in it.

Comment: I have file openerp-server.conf in /opt/odoo/odoo/debian directory. The value of the addons_path variable is "addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons". However, my Odoo application is using modules from "opt/odoo/odoo/addons". I could not find the file where this path is defined and how application knows to use this path "opt/odoo/odoo/addons" instead of  "addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons". Can you help to clarify this?

Comment: I have added new path in /opt/odoo/odoo/debian/openerp-server.conf but Odoo still can not see the new modules in Settings/Update Modules List.

Comment: I assume you've gone to Settings-->Modules-->Update Modules List and clicked the "Update" button?

Answer (score 2):

As of Odoo V8, the "default" addons_path in the odoo-server.conf file should read as follows (assuming you installed Odoo in the "/opt/odoo" path, otherwise change accordingly):

```
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons
```

If you also need to add another "custom" folder for additional modules, separate those with a comma, like this:

```
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/custom_modules
```