# How to get into the python shell within Odoo 8 environment?

Tags: python, shell, path, odoo-8, odoo

I would like to use the Odoo Framework from the shell.

I installed the module ["Shell command backport"](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/shell/) (technical name: `shell`), but I couldn't make it work.

```
$ ./odoo.py shell --addons-path=/opt/odoo_8/src/linked-addons -d database_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./odoo.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "./odoo.py", line 157, in main
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "/opt/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 58, in main
    for m in module.get_modules():
  File "/opt/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/modules/module.py", line 351, in get_modules
    plist.extend(listdir(ad))
  File "/opt/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/modules/module.py", line 346, in listdir
    return map(clean, filter(is_really_module, os.listdir(dir)))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons'
```

Where is defined the path `/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons`? I checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054026/where-openerp-odoo-finds-the-modules-path) as well.

If I don't write the addons path in the command the error appears again.

I read the answer of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293139/how-to-parse-odoo-in-python-console/34293569), I tried the module and the script option but they didn't work. What should I do to make it work? Any hint would help.

Comment: I suppose it is computed from odoo8 root dir. As a workaround I would attempt to create this directory even if it is empty.

Comment: Check your .opererp_serverrc for the user you are executing the command as. In the users home directory you will find this file. There may be reference to the addons path. The path it appears to be looking for `/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons` differs from what you have specified in your command. If this path is not referenced in your config then grep `/opt/odoo_8/src/OCA/OCB/openerp/modules/module.py`. There may be a static reference. I would check your config files.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I did the workaround and now I don't get the error but it returns to the bash, it seems that nothing happens

Comment: @phillipstack I don't use the configuration file. The module descriptions of the module says it is not necessary. I'm going to update the question right now with the link to the module

Comment: Have you checked your home directory for the file I suggested? The file is created automatically by odoo and if you dont use a config file odoo will use its default config. You must at look for it and see if there is a reference to this file path.

Comment: I added a link to other similar question as well. I hope to find the solution soon. I'm not interested in the solution with oerplib because it doesn't use the same methods

Comment: @phillipstack ah! you are right, I'm going to change it, let's see

Comment: If there is a reference and this solves your problem do you mind if I post this as a solution and you toss me a bone and mark my answer correct?

Comment: @phillipstack mm it didn't solve the problem, it returns to the bash again :-( the same effect as if I create the empty folder

Comment: Have you added `running_env = dev` to the `~/.openerp_serverrc` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125751/discussion-between-phillipstack-and-chesucr).

Comment: Finally I copied my original config file to the home directory of my user and it worked. So many thanks @phillipstack. But I don't see any difference with the `running_env = dev` parameter. You can write the comment with the path solution as an answer to my quiestion

Comment: Thanks! Glad you are on your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `.opererp_serverrc` for the user you are executing the command as. In the users home directory you will find this file. There may be reference to the `addons_path`. The path it appears to be looking for `/opt/odoo8/openerp/addons` differs from what you have specified in your command. I would check your config files.